# What techniques can be used to detect so called "black holes" (a spider trap) when creating a web crawler?

Tags: web-crawler

When creating a web crawler, you have to design somekind of system that gathers links and add them to a queue. Some, if not most, of these links will be dynamic, which appear to be different, but do not add any value as they are specifically created to fool crawlers.

**An example:**

We tell our crawler to crawl the domain evil.com by entering an initial lookup URL.

Lets assume we let it crawl the front page initially, evil.com/index

The returned HTML will contain several "unique" links:

- evil.com/somePageOne
- evil.com/somePageTwo
- evil.com/somePageThree

The crawler will add these to the buffer of uncrawled URLs.

When somePageOne is being crawled, the crawler receives more URLs:

- evil.com/someSubPageOne
- evil.com/someSubPageTwo

These appear to be unique, and so they are. They are unique in the sense that the returned content is different from previous pages and that the URL is new to the crawler, however it appears that this is only because the developer has made a "loop trap" or "black hole".

The crawler will add this new sub page, and the sub page will have another sub page, which will also be added. This process can go on infinitely. The content of each page is unique, but totally useless (it is randomly generated text, or text pulled from a random source). Our crawler will keep finding new pages, which we actually are not interested in.

These loop traps are very difficult to find, and if your crawler does not have anything to prevent them in place, it will get stuck on a certain domain for infinity.

**My question is, what techniques can be used to detect so called black holes?**

One of the most common answers I have heard is the introduction of a limit on the amount of pages to be crawled. However, I cannot see how this can be a reliable technique when you do not know what kind of site is to be crawled. A legit site, like Wikipedia, can have hundreds of thousands of pages. Such limit could return a false positive for these kind of sites.

Comment: Do you have an exmpmle of such a website so I can check it out and perhaps provide more solutions.

Comment: Not at the moment PeeHaa, but their existance is certain (there are numerous guides out there on how to create one on purpose as well), so in order to make a fail prove crawler such possibility has to be taken into account.

Comment: The main way to avoid traps like these is to make sure your crawler adheres to robots.txt, which I'm surprised no one mentioned. It's relatively common practice to put disallow rules for web-crawler-hostile portions of the site into robots.txt. In fact, it's also common practice to put **intentionally** hostile spider traps under disallow sections, so e-mail harvesters and whatnot get what they have coming to them.

Comment: @ParthianShot The purpose of robots.txt is not to inform crawlers of spider traps, but to request the crawler not to index pages (for many possible reasons). Just because a url is mentioned in disallow in robots.txt, does not mean it is a spider trap, and just because it is not under disallow does not make it a spider trap either.

Comment: @KaizerSozay `The purpose of robots.txt is not to inform crawlers of spider traps, but to request the crawler not to index pages (for many possible reasons).` ...Yes, which is why it works so well most of the time. It's a heuristic. A really good heuristic. And that's as good as you'll get, because you can only use heuristics for something like this.

Comment: The more you comply to standards, the fewer headaches you'll have, generally. Because If I'm hosting a [Sugarplum](http://www.devin.com/sugarplum/) installation, I'm putting that in my robots.txt under Disallow, and I'm linking to it in a subtle way from within my site, for exactly this purpose. To flush out the crawlers acting in bad faith, and to reward the crawlers that behave well.

Answer (score 17):

Well, you've asked very challenging question. There are many issues:

**First**, do you think someone would do something like that to prevent web spidering? A web spider could act as **DoS** attack if it would got stuck in such structure.

**Secondly**, if page is made for users, how would they react to large number of senseless links linking to random generated 'trash sites'? This links should be invisible for user, either a few of them or they would be hidden somehow - you should then check, if links have display: none, 1 px font etc.

**Third**, how google would behave? Well, **google** does not index everything it can. It adds links to queue, but not follows them immediately. He does not like to follow deeply referenced links, that are not linked from pages previously indexed. It makes him not index everything, but index what users are most likely to visit is finally visited. Otherwise such pages as you describe will be extremally often used by **SEO** spammers ;)

I would build priority queue. Each link to each URL adds 1 point priority (more, when from main page). Pages with priority 1 are at the end list. I would limit visited pages count, so at worst case I would visity most important pages. I would be suspitious againt pages that contains too much links with too little content. In short words, simulate google behaviour as much as it is needed.

Comment: How would this handle a calendar that creates infinite dynamic links to the "next month" etc.? The link would have the same "deepness" as other legit links.

Comment: Yes, right, it would have the same deepness. In typical site, however, there are more links to the same page. For example, in blogs, where there is a calendar, a calendar page has link to articles. Each of articles has links to current/previous/next month page and is linked by tags, previous article etc. Algorithm I propose would, however, index this structure anyway, in case page limit is not reached other way, f.g. by a lot of infinite loops.

Comment: I agree a priority queue might work. The crawler would then tend to defer work on traps, and instead prioritize useful work. If the crawler has a time limit, the work left undone when the crawler reaches the time limit will be the traps. This has the advantage of never falsely rejecting large sites such as Wikipedia, and the priority computation can be tweaked to optimize the rejection.

Comment: @Raedwald the priority computation is the problem though. You cannot compute how useful a page is without first crawling it. Also, a time limit would be different for Wikipedia than for a small site yet you do not know what kind of site you are dealing with beforehand. I'm looking for a more detailed answer that actually goes into how this would work, because when I think it out it doesn't seem to be as doable as illustrated in this answer.

Comment: "You cannot compute how useful a page is without first crawling it." I beleive you can: maintain a "site priority" for each site; worsen that priority each time you find a URL in that site that references that site; use that "site priority" as the priority for each newly found URL in that site.

Comment: @Raedwald, so Wikipedia which has a lot of URLs referencing to itself would get a very low site priority and not get fully indexed?

Comment: @Tom: Wilipedia will still get indexed, but slower than other sites. In effect the crawler would tend towards breadth-first rather than depth-first searching of the WWW.

Comment: @Raedwald one issue here is that my crawler is supposed to crawl a set of domains, not the entire world wide web. More importantly, if it does see the "next month" link as a valid URL, it will still get stuck on those links for this particular domain and never get to the links that do matter.

Comment: "my crawler is supposed to crawl a set of domains". OK, so the crawler tends towards breadth-first rather than depth-first seach of *that set of domains* rather than the entire WWW.

Comment: @Raedwald, that's easier said then done. Did you think this through? For example, even if it goes per level per domain it will not succeed for some domains that have these dynamic URLs (eg. the calendar). Sure, the crawler will move on to the next domain, but it will not succeed crawling the relevant information from the previous domain. If you did, please consider posting a more detailed answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Any solution is going to be heuristic at best, so you'll have to settle for less-than-perfect results. I would have thought that the page limit approach would work quite well if implemented properly.

You could put a limit on the number of pages to be crawled *without leaving the domain*; this doesn't prevent all of the pages from being indexed, since if the spider bails before a particular page is reached, there'll probably be more paths to that page that enter the domain "closer" to it, allowing it to be reached before the cut off.

Remember also that without such a limit, a spider could get stuck on a legit site like Wikipedia for a very long time, simply due to the overwhelming amount of content.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a solution to detect black-holes as there are many reasons a site could create an infinite number of pages for good reason and it would be difficult to say anything about the content of such a site. For this reason I propose a change of approach which prevents spiders from digging indefinitely:

I think it would be better to develop a strategy where by each page has a page ranking value assigned. The links too have a value assigned, all identical links then produce a final target ranking (potential return on searching the page).

A spider should only be allowed to crawl for a period of time as defined by the potential return.  Now spiders are dropped, mine data, and are lifted and repositioned where the demand is.

In this way a server will not have it's spiders trapped searching pages indefinitely as they are continuously reassigned to where the demand is highest.

Comment: How do you assign a page ranking to a page? And how do you do this without first crawling this page?

Comment: Well you need to crawl a page for a page ranking.  But you should be able to assign a value to links you haven't visited.  The more links you collect from different sites which point to the same page will elevate that link rank.  The text before, after and in the link should be used to determine probable subjects in the target (correlation of related terms I bet can be found this way).  How this comes together is that people who search are supplying a demand to the system altering the value of the search terms, the search engine then tries to meet this supply.

Comment: "You should be able to assign a value to links you haven't visited", this all sounds rather vague to be honest. You suggest that these bad pages must have a lot of equal content, which is not true. I'm also not trying to build a search engine (thus I do not have a list with related words). If you could expand your answer with how this algorithm actually works, that'd be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Equal content? My first line is contrary to that.  Of course it is vague, how can a fitness be applied without knowing what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

If you were building a large scale web crawler, it would make sense to take the following approach:

- First crawl links explicitly mentioned in the `sitemap.xml` or the site map files mentioned by the `site map index file`. Since a `sitemap.xml` is expected to have no more that 50,000 urls, and a site map index is expected to have no more than 1000 index files, it would be reasonable to expect that if you crawled these links first, you would have a reasonable index of the sites content. Since it would makes sense to put the more important urls in the site map. This could be up to 50 million urls! Thats a lot, I'm not sure there would be many sites that have more than 50 million urls. Wikipedia claims there are 32,663,401 pages according to their active counters. So if you follow this scheme, you can at least crawl wikipedia which is an achievement (since it would take a while). Note that this tactic will help you crawl only sites that have actually created a site map, but it is more likely that a useful website would have a site map!, as opposed to one that doesn't.
- The next step could be to make a list of the urls that are not mentioned in the site map (we can prioritise which ones to crawl later)
- Crawl other web domains following the first two steps.
- Once you run out of web domains to crawl (If you do run out of domains to crawl, that is quite an achievement!), then you can start page ranking all the urls, including the ones you haven't crawled yet (from step 2!)
- It is more likely the urls from step 2 are valid urls, if other external domains with a high page rank have linked to them. Therefore you can prioritise which urls to crawl. If no external domains have linked to urls from step 2, then it is more likely that the content is either not so useful to people who have visited the page, or no one has visited the page, or it is a spider trap. Now, it possible that a url which does not have any external domains linking to it, has no links to it because it has never been indexed before, and no one knows it exists. It may be worth it to index this page, but as you go "deeper down", the pages it links to should be treated with less importance.
- Another useful trick, (but much more complicated), is to check whether the text / urls on a page are readable. Some sites try to hide text / urls by making it the same color as the background so they aren't immediately visible to humans, but can be used to trick machines. Likewise some content can be hidden using CSS. These should be detected by your crawler / indexed to lower the score of a particular page, and give it less importance when determining which url to crawl next.
- Finally, once crawling is complete, you need to begin the next cycle of crawling and repeat the above process! This time if you find external domains linking to the urls from step 2, its page rank goes up! And you can now drill deeper! This way you should have a reasonably good index for more common content, and avoid spider traps.

Another step I haven't mentioned is, "Processing / Indexing of crawled content". This is a really big step - but since your question was more about crawling rather than how to build a full fledged information retrieval system I didn't mention it earlier.

Most legitimate content, tends to make sense from a Natural Language Processing perspective. For example, a human being who reads a page can immediately tell if the page is just a collection of random words strung together or whether it is real content which is trying to express an idea. By processing data from "known" legitimate sites, one can build up a set of rules and heuristics about how a particular language is supposed to look. This can be used to tell your web crawler if a particular link contains gibberish or real content. This can be used to rate a url and determine how important it is to follow.

As mentioned in other answers, you can also hash the content of each url, to determine "uniqueness". Content which is identical doesn't need to be parsed for urls again - so this lets you avoid traps that reuse the same content. Natural language processing should help you avoid random gibberish.

A third problem is pages that are dynamically created by using legitimate content from other websites. This is a more complicated problem, but again, you can give less importance to these by using page rank. If you can actually build a scalable system which can crawl all the urls mentioned in the site maps of every domain on the internet, that it quite an achievement, and also means you are very rich and powerful since you probably have thousands of computers at your disposal. Being such a rich guy you should probably focus on more important things and have your engineers figure this stuff out. XD

Comment: On a side note, there is no reason to crawl all of Wikipedia. It is much faster (and less wasteful of their resources) to just download the database dumps that they provide for free, and crawl/index the local copy.

Comment: I'm aware of that - crawling wikipedia was just an example exercise to illustrate the larger problem of crawling all the links on the web. There isn't a database dump of the web... XD

Answer (score 3):

Content is the difference between a black hole and a legitimate site, like Wikipedia. While WP is indeed a huge website dimensionally, each URL contains kilobytes of legitimate data. A spider trap site might be equally as 'big', but the pages won't contain anything much: it's utterly perverse to waste server resources and bandwidth generating sizeable quantities of gibberish data simply to tie up a web crawler.

Rather than putting upper limits on breadth or depth of a site's URL tree (which would trap content-rich sites like WP), perhaps track the number of pages scanned which are below some floor of 'useful size'. You can then pull the eject handle on your spider once that count exceeds some acceptable limit.

Comment: You're suggesting to create somekind of algorithm that flags content as useful or potentially useless, and use this as a counter? Wouldn't the algorithm have different needs for each site?

Comment: Tom, simpler than that. I am suggesting flagging any page under a certain byte count as a potential trap - in other words, trying to distinguish between 'possible content' and 'possible trap' based on the assumption that 'traps' will be very small. If the page is only 40 or 50 bytes (html header, empty body) then it's probably useless. Too many of them and you bail out.  A Wikipedia page, for example, is much larger.

Comment: That can easily be circumvented by generating/copying large amounts of content for each page, though.

Comment: Will, I know, which is why the second sentence in the answer discusses exactly that. Why bother generating large amounts of junk data just to fool a spider, when it costs you money in bandwidth and server resources?

Comment: the question is not whether it's senseful to build such trap (although I could think of some reasons), but it is certain that is's possible. Another probably more important reason is that some sites may have these traps by accident. For example, a calendar site might create URLs based on a date - or it might just have a "next month" link which is also dynamically generated. In order to create a fail safe crawler, all these possibilities have to be taken into account. It is certainly possible to circumvent them, just look at the bigger crawlers like search engines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can add a limit of the length of an URL to crawl.

Also most webservers have a limit on the length of an URL. So you shouldn't be looped infinitely.

Found a doc on the matter. Don't know whether it still is up2date though.

Check it out: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Also you can limit the 'deepness' of pages.

Like domain.com/page/subpage/subsubpage/subsubsubpage/subsubsubsubpage/subsubsubsubsubpage/etc/etc/etc/etc/etc

Comment: Yes but what's to stop the evil doer from randomly generating a url which isn't nested. URL are long enough and can consist of enough characters to make a lot of possible combinations.

Comment: Can you provide an example website with an 'blackhole'?

Comment: Indeed, there are way too many possible combinations even with a short url.

Comment: You shouldn't use anything about the URL.  There are way too many instances of sites putting an excessive amount of parameters up there.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you `MD5(the content of the URL)` ?

I know it's not the most delicate solution, but you can detect some duplicated content. You'll have to create a unique md5 field (in a DB or similar) and check each url content against this field.

If the page has something different in each request (ie: timestamp), this solution won't work.

Comment: This won't work in almost any case because the content may also be generated to, say, include the url. So if the url change, the content also change, so the md5 will be different. In a "calendar" case where you can go to next month, and next month, and next month, etc, the content will show something like "Events for May 2065", hence a different md5.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I'm just coming across this and want to point out that while MD5 will not work for duplicate detection (a change of a single byte will result in completely different output), there are *locality sensitive hashing* techniques that are designed to map similar (but not necessarily duplicate) content close to each other, and these *can* be used for near-duplicate detection for crawlers. Popular examples of these sorts of hashes are simhash and minhash.

Answer (score 0):

The content on some poorly designed sites can sometimes be highly redundant but I don't see any legit reason to be avoiding black-hole traps.

The purpose of a blackhole is to detect robots that fail to/refuse to respect the /robots.txt file (if one exists) or rel="nofollow" attributes on links. Such robots are usually used to scrape email addresses and other information for the express purpose of spamming people or selling that data to spammers.

Links to blackholes are usually hidden so that normal users don't accidentally get trapped. They are also not a problem to Google,Bing, etc because they do what the site owner has asked them to do (i.e respect the owners robots.txt). The only people who get trapped are those that don't give a *^*&@ and poorly designed crawlers.